# Inject FFMPEG video converter directly into .NET C#?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, ffmpeg, progress-bar

How to implement [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) in .NET Core C#?

I'm using FFMPEG as a batch file, I prepared a jobs queue, then [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) picks queue rows to sending to the batch file to starting convert by FFMPEG.

I need to inform users by a progress bar, because of using [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) as a CLI third-party, it is unachievable.
Is there any `nuget` package or any way to inject [FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org/) into .NET?

Comment: See the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) class.

Comment: Thanks, but FFMPEG is a third-party and process of video converting depends on server hardware, I think I can't get the process state by System.Diagnostics.

Comment: You can run process `cmd`, using the ffmpeg code in your batch file as an argument. Then redirect the standard output of the cmd process and extract necessary information from there. I'll see if I can make an answer.

Comment: Actually I've done this solution right now, but I don't want to use batch files, actually this solution is mess because of using Text manipulation. I need to know is there any best practice for video converting.